# Weird behaviour in compilation, have to save Main class every time, even though there are no changes(Java)

Tags: java

I have a Java program that uses 4 classes that are instantiated, plus a class for main. When I added the last class I noticed this strange thing, where my saved changes in this class were not present in the program after compilation. I noticed that I had to save main class as well, even though I did not make any changes to it.

I only use the main class file name in compilation.

I am not too experienced with java, but I'm pretty sure this has not been the case before.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you possibly add the name of the files and, at least, the structure of the project? I also doubt if it is java-related question or IDE-related? Therefore, I am also wondering what IDE do you use?

Comment: I use sublime for editing and compile on the command line. File names are Kirjakauppa.java, Yhteys.java, Asiakasistunto.java, Asiakaskyselyt.java, Kirjautumisavustaja.java, Superuser.java, Yllapitajaistunto.java and Yllapitokyselyt.java. These are all in the same folder.

Comment: Kirjakauppa.java is a main class that models a bookstore user interface. Asiakasistunto, Yllapitajaistunto and Superuser model for the actions of clients, bookstore admins, and the main admin. Rest of the classes include JDBC interactions to database for each role. This problem arouse int the Yllapitajaistunto.java file that handles the database queries of the bookstore admins.

Comment: So what happens  if you don't save the main clas?

Comment: If you compile on the command line, can you show the actual command you use? Most likely it is incorrect.

Comment: javac Kirjakauppa.java

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution to this. This one problematic class was only one that was not instantiated in the main, but in the other class. I created a dummy object from this class in my main and now everything works as intended.